# Why does my output file combine the first two lines together, and how can I separate them?

Tags: python, string, list, file

When ever I run the program it combines the first two items in my list. This is what I have in my input file:

```
programming
python
world
hello
```

The output file returns:

```
programmingpython
world
hello
```

This is the output I need:

```
programming
python
world
hello
```

This is the assignment: Suppose that we have a file words.txt that contains a list of English words, one word per line. Write Python program that will read words from that file and write these words to the output file out_words.txt in reverse order. That is the last word in the input file should be the first word in the output file and so on.

And this is what I have so far:

```
in_file = open("words.txt", "r")
out_file = open("out_words.txt", "w")
L = []
for line in in_file:
    L == L.append(line)
    reverse = L[::-1]
    string = "".join(reverse)
print(string, file=out_file)


in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Comment: I don't see how you would get that output.  The lines should be in reverse order, shouldn't they?  I suspect you are using a different input file than the one you have posted here.

Comment: It was the correct input file, I got it to for with another for loop and the split() fuction.

Comment: @JohnGordon This happens when the input file does not end with a newline character.

Comment: @blhsing A missing newline at the end of the file would cause `L[::-1]` to not reverse the lines?  Really?

Comment: @JohnGordon Oops I misread your comment. By "I don't see how you would get that output" I thought you were referring to the OP's "it combines the first two items in my list" issue when you were really talking about the fact that the OP's expected output is identical to the input, which must've been mis-typed/copied.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't set L as return value of L.append, also you don't need to put the reverse operation inside iteration (I guess it's spelling when you copy code here)

Try code as below:

```
in_file = open("words.txt", "r")
out_file = open("out_words.txt", "w")

# Read all of the words from the input file into a list.
L = []
for line in in_file:
    L.append(line)

reverse = L[::-1]
with open("out_words.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for word in reverse:
        print(word, file=out_file)

in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Comment: I found a way to do it but your code did help thank you!

Comment: This answer does not at all address the main issue of the question, that the last two words got joined together in the output.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with, I don't know if it makes sense but it works

```
in_file = open("words.txt", "r")
out_file = open("out_words.txt", "w")
L = []
for line in in_file:
    L.append(line)

reverse_string = L[::-1]
string = " ".join(reverse_string).split()

for item in string:
    print(item, file=out_file)

in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting an output with the first two words joined together is that your input file does not end with a newline character, so when you reverse the lines as a list of strings and then join them with an empty string, the last line without a newline gets joined with the second-last line without a separator.

You can use the [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method to split the file content by newlines but without keeping the newlines in the returning list of strings. By normalizing the input lines to be without newline characters, you can then easily output the list in reverse order with a newline as the separator using `print`:

```
with open('words.txt') as in_file, open("out_words.txt", "w") as out_file:
    print(*reversed(in_file.read().splitlines()), sep='\n', file=out_file)
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/ElaborateAmazingLaw